# How to use tabs not causing PEP warnings

Tags: python, pycharm, conventions, pep

I am using PyCharm and tabs.
If there is a function with a number of parameters to pass I can do like this, which works just fine:

```
return render(
    request,
    '/post/list.html',
    {'page': page, 'posts': posts}
)
```

But sometimes it just looks better and more compact like this:

```
return render(request, '/post/list.html',
              {'page': page, 'posts': posts})
```

Ant here is where things got a little more complicated. When using tabs I get `PEP 8: indentation contains mixed spaces and tabs` (because spaces are being used to make a visual under-indent.
Not using spaces at all:

```
return render(request, '/post/list.html',
    {'page': page, 'posts': posts})
```

also returns a `PEP` notification: `PEP 8: continuation line under-indented for visual alignment`

I see that using spaces (which is preferable according go `PEP`) would solve this issue but I was wondering if there is a solution for tab-users.

**EDIT:** I see everyone's sentiment about using tabs and spaces. I guess I will switch to spaces for now. But the question itself remains open. If you know how to make a pretty looking tab indents with alignment and without mixing tabs and spaces I will be interested to learn that. Thanks!

Comment: "tab-users", with minimal training, can be taught to use spaces ;)

Comment: No, there isn't - if you're using tabs you have to accept that you'll be over-/under-indented in these cases; as whitespace has semantic meaning in Python, mixing tabs and spaces is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah, but the idea of using arrow keys and backspace quadruple as many times as using tabs haunts my mind.

Comment: @ArtyomIlyin You can easily re-configure your choosen text editor so that pressing the tab key inserts 4 spaces (this is what I do in vim, via `set expandtab`)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Is there anything that would help with navigating or deleting 4 spaces at once? Insertion is not an issue.

Comment: @ArtyomIlyin In vim, it is easy to configure the backspace or other key to act this way- if you google search I'm sure there will be a solution for all popular editors

Comment: don't use tabs... ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert tabs to spaces or spaces to tabs by menu using `Edit -> Convert Indents -> To spaces` *(To tabs)* . Easier way is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and type *to*  and select the option you want to apply.

Also, please refer to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-style-python.html) pycharm docs (only first part). It lets you configure to convert tabs to spaces when tab is pressed.

EDIT:

Also, please read [this](https://pep8.org/#tabs-or-spaces) short PEP8 guide about tabs and spaces.
Basically:

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.

EDIT 2:

If you want to disable some warnings, when you see squiggly underline (usually yellow for warnings), place cursor at it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose *Ignore errors like this*.

[image: warnings]

You can also disable some types of warnings by `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections` and see more at *Python* category.

Comment: the second part of the answer is what you should rely on moving forward. Just don't use tabs as tabs, there is a reason PEP flags them.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to mention that, thank you. Spaces remain consistent over OSes while tabs can sometimes break it. That's why PEP8 suggest to use spaces. I added it as edit.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really correspond to my question. I know how to convert tabs to spaces and vice versa. What I don't know is how to make pretty looking indentation without PEP warnings. But I see the sentiment about using tabs :)

Comment: @DinkoPehar sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I do not want to just hide those warnings. I wanted to somehow make everything correct from PEP's perspective, but using tabs. And that under-indented alignment in continuation lines.

Comment: You can't change rules that are defined by python.org . You can only follow the rules or disable them so that pycharm doesn't bother you when you indent with tabs.

Answer (score -3):

> I am using PyCharm

Well, some like it indeed.

> and tabs

Now the answer is plain and simple: **DONT**. Never, ever. You want spaces, 4 of them, period.

Comment: honestly, not a super useful feedback: being able to enter 4 (or 2) spaces at once on the keyboard (by pressing tab) is very convenient, and can often avoid indentation errors. You should at least make clear that this is very different from actually using tabs in the file, which is what is not recommended (for a whole lot of good reasons). The answer above explains how to solve this, so it's way more actionable.

Besides, the first part of your reply is highly opinionated which is clearly against the guidelines of Stackoverflow.